# Serializing an array before sending it to an API end point

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, serialization, swift2

I am sending an array to an API endpoint, but the array is not going throuhg correctly. Here is what I have:

User:
name
email

So in my case I have a swift array of two users:

```
po userArray
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ [0] : <User: 0x7fa3ab597fd0>
  ▿ [1] : <User: 0x7fa3ab597bb0>
```

The JSON that the server expects is:

```
{users: [ {name:'john', email:'john@example.com'}, {name:'tom', email: 'tom@example.com' }]
```

What I'm sending:

```
'users' : userArray
```

But there seems to be a serialization issue. What the server is getting from me is this:

```
'users': ['MyApp.User', 'MyApp.User']
```

I'm using AlamoFire to send my PUT request.

Do I need to do convert the array to JSON before sending it out? I'm new to Swift and any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to show your code specifically how you add params to send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `description` property for the custom class `User`

```
class User : NSObject
{ 
   var name : String
   var age : String

   override var description : String
   {
      get{
         return ["name" : self.name, "age" : self.age].description
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So the class needs to inherit from NSObject as well? User is a subclass of BaseModel in my case, and so it is not letting me do multiple inheritance. If I inherit from NSObject on my BaseModel, some of my other classes that happen to have a description property are failing. Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you inherit NSObject. You just need to  override description property everywhere, I'm doing the same in my project. or you can use `AnyObject` type objects instead writing your own class

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your User object into dictionary. Than you should add as value not array of users, but array of dictionaries.